# Tensorflow seq2seq Sequence loss function : trying to get per-iteration cross-entropy loss (to avoid OOM)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to add a mechanism so that the cross entropy loss calculated in seq2seq.sequence_loss (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/sequence_loss) is done so not in a batch but per iteration

I tried to use tf.while_loop and tf.scan , but have been facing issues for 2 days. My (vain)attempt with tf.scan is below.

This function is supposed to replace and emulate the result of this one : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/loss.py

Firstly , can it even be done? 
If yes , where am I messing up ?
Any help would be appreciated :D

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
    from __future__ import division
    from __future__ import print_function
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
    from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
    from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
    from tensorflow.python.ops import nn_ops



def sequence_loss(logits, targets, weights, average_across_timesteps=True, average_across_batch=True,
                  softmax_loss_function=None, name=None):
    timestep_del = array_ops.shape(logits)[1]
    num_classes = array_ops.shape(logits)[2]
    logi = array_ops.shape(logits)[0]

    timesteps = array_ops.reshape(logits, [-1, logi])
    logits_flat = array_ops.reshape(logits, [-1, num_classes])

    timestep_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=None, name='timestep_holder')
    stacked_tensors = tf.stack(values=[logits_flat, tf.to_float(targets)], axis=0)

    timesteps = math_ops.reduce_sum(weights, axis=[1], name='timestep_from_weight')

    with ops.name_scope(name, "sequence_loss", [logits, targets, weights]):

        def scan_func(nothing, stacked_tensors):

            logits_flat, targets = tf.unstack(value=stacked_tensors, axis=0)

            # reshaping logits to put in the softmax:
            logits_flatr = array_ops.reshape(logits_flat, [-1, timestep_del])

            scan_timestep = array_ops.reshape(logits_flat, [-1, logi])


            # reshaping target
            reshaped_target = array_ops.reshape(targets, [-1])

            # matmul to get logits for softmax per timestep

            logit_scan = tf.concat(values=[tf.to_float(logits_flatr), tf.to_float(scan_timestep)], name='logit_scan',
                                   axis=0)

            if softmax_loss_function is None:
                crossent = nn_ops.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=reshaped_target,
                                                                           logits=tf.to_float(logit_scan))
                crossent *= array_ops.reshape(weights, [-1])

            else:
                crossent = softmax_loss_function(labels=reshaped_target, logits=tf.to_float(logit_scan))
                crossent *= array_ops.reshape(weights, [-1])

            print("\n the loss is :", crossent)
            return crossent

        # elems : tuple of logits and label per TS
        init = tf.zeros_like(timesteps)

        print("\n\n\n TIMESTEPS: \n\n:", timesteps, "\n\n\n Shape", tf.shape(timesteps), "\n\n")

        scan_crossent = tf.scan(fn=scan_func, elems=timesteps, infer_shape=False, initializer=init)
        print("\n\n\n tf.scan output : \n\n:", scan_crossent, "\n\n\n Shape", tf.shape(scan_crossent), "\n\n")



    return scan_crossent

"""GOOGLE DOCUMENTAION:Weighted cross-entropy loss for a sequence of logits.
      Depending on the values of `average_across_timesteps` and
      `average_across_batch`, the return Tensor will have rank 0, 1, or 2 as these
      arguments reduce the cross-entropy at each target, which has shape
      `[batch_size, sequence_length]`, over their respective dimensions. For
      example, if `average_across_timesteps` is `True` and `average_across_batch`
      is `False`, then the return Tensor will have shape `[batch_size]`.
      Args:
        logits: A Tensor of shape
          `[batch_size, sequence_length, num_decoder_symbols]` and dtype float.
          The logits correspond to the prediction across all classes at each
          timestep.

        targets: A Tensor of shape `[batch_size, sequence_length]` and dtype
          int. The target represents the true class at each timestep.

        weights: A Tensor of shape `[batch_size, sequence_length]` and dtype
          float. `weights` constitutes the weighting of each prediction in the
          sequence. When using `weights` as masking, set all valid timesteps to 1
          and all padded timesteps to 0, e.g. a mask returned by `tf.sequence_mask`.

        average_across_timesteps: If set, sum the cost across the sequence
          dimension and divide the cost by the total label weight across timesteps.

        average_across_batch: If set, sum the cost across the batch dimension and
          divide the returned cost by the batch size.
        softmax_loss_function: Function (labels, logits) -> loss-batch
          to be used instead of the standard softmax (the default if this is None).
          **Note that to avoid confusion, it is required for the function to accept
          named arguments.**
        name: Optional name for this operation, defaults to "sequence_loss".
      Returns:
        A float Tensor of rank 0, 1, or 2 depending on the
        `average_across_timesteps` and `average_across_batch` arguments. By default,
        it has rank 0 (scalar) and is the weighted average cross-entropy
        (log-perplexity) per symbol.
      Raises:
        ValueError: logits does not have 3 dimensions or targets does not have 2
                    dimensions or weights does not have 2 dimensions.
      """
```